# How to get information from the navfn planner execution

Tags: ros, navfn, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!
I'm working on a A.I. project and I need to know how to obtain information from the navfn global planner during execution.
In more details, what should I do in order to call the methods listed in the navfn::NavFn class reference (http://www.ros.org/doc/api/navfn/html/classnavfn_1_1NavFn.html#a991e667731691eb111cddc786e2d02d0) to retrieve run-time informations and can later work with them? The information I need is the one returned by getLastPathCost().

Any suggestion would help.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45434/how-to-get-information-from-the-navfn-planner-execution/) by [Fabio Signorini](https://answers.ros.org/users/3353/fabio-signorini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

NavFn can be used standalone just to generate plans, or as a plugin to move_base.
I assume you mean in the latter case. What I would do in your place is replace navfn_node with a custom global planner, that additionally sends all information you need to a topic.

Basically you would copy the whole navfn ROS package, then remove all c++ source file except src/navfn_node.cpp. Then add a topic publisher and change makePlanService() service to also publish on your custom topic.

Then you need to adapt filenames, the package manifest, plugin file etc. Create a launchfile for move_base (by copying the one you used so far), and declare your custom global planner as a replacement to navfn. Use this launchfile instead of the one you used so far, and move_base should use your custom global planner, and every time move_base calls the makePlan Service, you would get a message on your topic telling you what you need to know.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3